# Memory release in pthread TLS destructor is not detected by valgrind/massif

Tags: linux, pthreads, valgrind, thread-local-storage, massif

Symptoms:
I allocate TLS key with a destructor, create a bundle of threads and pass the TLS key to each thread. Each thread allocates memory and sets its pointer in TLS, the TLS destructor deallocates memory. I wait for threads to finish before app exits.
The app is run under valgrind/massif that reports this memory not deallocated.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pthread_key_t* key = new pthread_key_t();
  pthread_key_create(key, my_destructor);

  pthread_t threads[32000];

  for(int i=0; i<32000; ++i)
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, my_thread, key);

  for(int i=0; i<32000; ++i)
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

In the thread runner I allocate the memory and set it up in the TLS:

```
extern "C" void* my_thread(void* p)
{
  pthread_setspecific(*(pthread_key_t*)p, malloc(100));

  return NULL;
}
```

In the TLS destructor, I release the memory:

```
extern "C" void my_destructor(void *p)
{
  free(p);
}
```

I run this under valgrind/massif 3.19 with the following options:

```
  --tool=massif
  --heap=yes
  --pages-as-heap=yes
  --log-file=/tmp/my.log
  --massif-out-file=/tmp/my.massif.log
```

Then I run `ms_print /tmp/my.massif.log`. I am getting the leaks reported like the following:

```
| ->01.75% (67,108,864B) 0x76F92D0: new_heap (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
| | ->01.75% (67,108,864B) 0x76F98D3: arena_get2.isra.3 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
| |   ->01.75% (67,108,864B) 0x76FF77D: malloc (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
| |     ->01.75% (67,108,864B) 0x410300: my_thread (threadsT.cpp:136)
| |       ...
| |       <skipped by author>
| |       ...
| |             
| ->00.00% (73,728B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
```

...while I would not expect anything reported leaked at all.

I added the instrumentation to my_destructor and manually verified that:

- it is invoked, indeed
- it deallocates the memory, as it is supposed to do

Is there something apparent I am doing wrong here that makes valgrind/massif report these?
Is it a valgrind/massif limitation that it cannot detect the memory deallocation when invoked from TLS destructors?

Building and running that with `gcc 4.9.4` on `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)`.

Comment: You absolutely leak at least `*key`.  Having allocated memory for it via `new`, it persists until you `delete` it, which you never do.  Why do you not simply declare a `pthread_key_t` instead of a pointer to one?  And use the `&` operator to get its address where needed?

Comment: If anything else is being leaked then we would need a [mre] to sort that out.

Comment: Side note: if all your destrucor needs to do is call `free()`, then you can use `free()` itself as the destructor instead of creating a wrapper function.

Comment: I leak *key intentionally (for reasons outside of that scope). If it is in the way of analysis, it can be changed as you said.
This code _is_ a minimal reproducible example.
Just run it under valgrind/massif, use ms_print to beautify the results and see the output file.

Comment: Thank you for advice about using the destructor instead of calling free(), but this code just demonstrates the issue with valgrind/massif. It is not the real production code that I had been working on when ran into that problem.

Comment: I'm interested in this as I've been doing a lot of work on the Valgrind code for TLS handling recently (not for Linux though). Does your code run cleanly with Memcheck, Helgrind and DRD?

Comment: @NSH, I built an executable from the code presented, except reducing the number of threads to 300.  Valgrind's only complaint about it was that a single 4-byte block was still allocated at program exit.  When I modified the program per my earlier suggestion, so that the TSD key was automatically allocated instead of dynamically allocated, that issue was resolved -- valgrind reported all heap blocks freed before program termination.  Votikng to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @John Bolinger the OP's question is about `massif`.

Comment: I posted a more generic [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803574/valgrind-massif-does-not-see-memory-deallocation-done-from-another-thread) that may or may not be explaining the cause of the reported leak int TLS destructor.

Comment: @PaulFloyd RE "Does your code run cleanly with Memcheck, Helgrind and DRD?" 
I did not try it, because I have not seen any complications with that for the code example I posted (which demonstrates the issue). As for the real production code... it is another story. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second answer, this time concentrating on the 'leak' aspect.

Massif isn't really a leak detector. It's for profiling heap use.

If I compile the example (with 320 threads) then at the end I get about 89 million bytes  still allocated. That is made up of

75% the arena used by malloc called from start_thread
9% pthread_create
15% loading shared libraries

None of that looks like much of a concern to me. I assume that the start_thread memory is the pthread stack cache.

If I use massif for profiling malloc/new, then the last sample is

```
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
73      2,929,610            2,360            2,308            52            0
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you mean that I just misread the report?
Also, about the calloc from strart_thread: IIRC glibc does use the cache of the thread stacks, but it is limited by 40Mb, no? Where would the rest (~89-40 = ~49) would come from?

Comment: Good point. `stack_cache_maxsize`  is indeed 40Mbytes. I don't know where the other 49Mbytes is being used.

Comment: @nsh, yes, I think you misread the report.  And maybe you performed a different analysis than you thought you were performing, too, because I note that if I leave the `--pages-as-heap` option turned off then I get an analysis that shows the reported usage come back down to almost zero by the last time slice.  And, as I observed on the question, valgrind/memcheck does not detect any leaks (other than the key).

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right. `--pages-as-heap` makes valgrind/massif leave allocation in the report, apparently because GLBIC per thread malloc cache has to operate on cache page with mmap - and it never munmap this page, keeping the cache alive till the process exits. This mmap is reported giving an impression the allocation is leaked.
Without `--pages-as-heap` the deallocation is accounted for.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return status for your thread creation. It's unlikely that you are succeeding in creating 32000 threads.

A bit of Valgrind source:

```
coregrind/pub_core_options.h:#define MAX_THREADS_DEFAULT 500
coregrind/m_scheduler/scheduler.c:   VG_(printf)("Use --max-threads=INT to specify a larger number of threads\n"
```

Assuming that this is amd64 Linux, I believe that the default pthread stack size is 8Mbytes. That means you need 256Gbytes for stack memory. Does your machine have that much?

Please try the following

1. Use `pthread_attr_setstacksize` to set the stack sizes to `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN` (16k).
2. Run Valgrind with --max-threads=32001

Even with the above you may still hit some Valgrind limits such as VG_N_SEGMENTS.

If you see a message like

"Valgrind: FATAL: VG_N_SEGMENTS is too low.
Increase it and rebuild.
Exiting now."

Then you will need to rebuild Valgrind with an increased limit.

Comment: I the more enhanced test, I do check for the result of thread creation and, actually, the test max number of threads fluctuates (I allocate as much as possible).
However, I can observe the same valgrind/massif reporting with using, say 300 threads. Therefore, it does not seem to me that it is the number threads used is the reason why valgrind/massif cannot report the memory deallocation invoked from TLS destructor.